# Access issue with restTemplatebuider

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

I use spring boot and spring security.

In my rest controller, i have one method

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

        http.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

        // CSRF tokens handling
        //http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/rest")
@RestController
public class MemberController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/members/card")
    public boolean hasCardIdValid(@RequestBody String cardId) {
        return memberService.hasCardIdValid(cardId);
    }
}
```

In another spring boot application, i try to call hasCreditCard method

```
@Autowired
    public GlobalScan(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder,  @Value("${main.server.url}") String mainServerUrl,   @Value("${commerce.username}") String commerceUsername, @Value("${commerce.password}")String commercePassword) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthorization(commerceUsername, commercePassword).rootUri(mainServerUrl).build();
    }

I do a call with this code

Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
vars.put("cardId", cardId);

boolean accessAllowed = restTemplate.getForObject("/rest/members/card/" , Boolean.class, vars);
```

i get this message

```
2016-11-02 16:20:50.601 DEBUG 7139 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/rest/members/card/'; against '/login'
2016-11-02 16:20:50.601 DEBUG 7139 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/rest/members/card/'; against '/rest/**'
2016-11-02 16:20:50.601 DEBUG 7139 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /rest/members/card/; Attributes: [authenticated]
2016-11-02 16:20:50.601 DEBUG 7139 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-11-02 16:20:50.602 DEBUG 7139 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3d300693, returned: -1
2016-11-02 16:20:50.602 TRACE 7139 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Publishing event in org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2bdd8394: org.springframework.security.access.event.AuthorizationFailureEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /rest/members/card/]
2016-11-02 16:20:50.606 DEBUG 7139 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
```

On my main app, i use a form login to connect to the app, like you can see in the spring security config.

From my other app how to call a ws without form login?

tried to call ws with this

```
 final RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(timeout * 1000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout * 1000).setSocketTimeout(timeout * 1000).build();

 final BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
 credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope("http://localhost", 8080, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("bob", "smith"));
 final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();

 final ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

 ResponseEntity<MemberDto> member = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/rest/members/1", MemberDto.class);
```

result: http://pastebin.com/psNKPUtM

Comment: I'm not sure this will fix your problem but the various `@Enable...` annotations often "disable" spring boot defaults... it's really painful... but then sometimes you need them. Try removing those.

Also if you could show the annotations on your test class and how restTemplate is configured...

Comment: i tried only with EnableWebSecurity, but it include EnableGlobalAuthentication and Configuration but get same issue. how restTemplate is configured is already showed. I don't have test class.

Comment: How can you use basic authentication in the Spring Boot client, when server app accepts form login?

Answer (score 1):

The default password in spring security is configured by the following property: `security.user.password=YOUR_PASSWORD`
This should be done in your main app where you have security configuration and which you are trying to call.

> You can change the password by providing a security.user.password.
>   This and other useful properties are externalized via
>   SecurityProperties (properties prefix "security").

So, if you didn't update the property to match the password in `commerce.password` spring will reject your authorization and you will get 401. By default it uses some random generated password it prints to the console during the start. [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html)

Comment: commerce.username and its password are used in the restTemplate. theses info are supposing to be used to log to the system, nothing to do with default password generated by spring security. If my main system have user x, y z... i supposing to be able to use them when i do a call to the system.

Comment: Ok, then it's not clear what's happening on your main app. Can you please turn on TRACE logging level for your main app and check what it logs when you try to do a request.

Comment: Now, I would go and place a breakpoint into FilterSecurityInterceptor to debug and walk through till the org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired()

I think this is where for some reason your anonymous authentication is returned instead of checking your headers.

Also try to put a breakpoint on authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
I expect it to be hit first time you send a request after application restart.

Answer (score 1):

You are configuring `formLogin()` but you try to use an http Basic Auth in your RestTemplate.
For requests via http REST I suggest that you change your configuration to use basic auth:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

    http.httpBasic();
    http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

    // CSRF tokens handling
    //http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}
```

If you need both I think you can configure both.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add BASIC auth to your existing configuration

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
           ....
       .and()
       .formLogin() // <------ Keep this
           ....
       .and()
       .httpBasic() // <------ Add BASIC Auth
       .and()
           .....;
   }
   ```
2. Write a simple client using RestTemplate

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter())));
       HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.set("Authorization", "Basic YOUR_BASE64_ENCODED_CREDENTIALS");
       MediaType applicationJson = new MediaType("application","json");
       headers.setContentType(applicationJson);
       headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(applicationJson));
       ResponseEntity<YourResponseObject> resp = rest.exchange("http://URL/rest/yourendpoint", HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers), YourResponseObject.class);

       System.out.println(resp.getBody());
   ```

   }

YOUR_BASE64_ENCODED_CREDENTIALS => If use use Java 8 you can use `java.util.Base64`, otherwise use commons-codec to do that or something else.

**Update:** 
Spring boot reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-httpsecurity

Comment: tried to use both, but form login stoped to work... seem like password don't work... need to send a header with  authorization otherwise that don't work...

Comment: I just tested what I have suggested here. It worked. Also take a look at Spring Boot docs. Looks like it is the default auto-configuration: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-httpsecurity. Which spring security and spring boot versions you are running with? Do you have custom auth filters somewhere?

Comment: Anyway in non-spring boot apps, you have to use two separate `@Configuration` with `@Order` to secure **two separate endpoints** with different configurations, such as formLogin() and httpBasic(),but it is not important here since you want to support both.